# Convert value from dict to list in a dictionary: value is type list to value is type dictionary

Tags: python

How can I convert from:

```
{'a': [2], 'b': [2], 'c': [1], 'd': [1]}
```

to

```
{'a': 2, 'b': 2, 'c': 1, 'd': 1}
```

I tried:

```
for key, value in numbersOfFollowersDict.items():
    numbersOfFollowersDict[key] = dict(value)
print(numbersOfFollowersDict)
```

But error appear:

```
    numbersOfFollowersDict[key] = dict(value)
TypeError: cannot convert dictionary update sequence element #0 to a sequence
```

Comment: The title says from dict to list, the example requests from list to int and the code tries to convert from list to dict. What are you trying to do? And what would be the purpose of such modification? It looks like a bad design

Answer (score 3):

You can use unpacking in a dictionary comprehension:

```
d = {'a': [2], 'b': [2], 'c': [1], 'd': [1]}
new_d = {a:b for a, [b] in d.items()}
```

Output:

```
{'a': 2, 'b': 2, 'c': 1, 'd': 1}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can `dict comprehension` here

```
>>> d = {'a': [2], 'b': [2], 'c': [1], 'd': [1]}
>>> output = {k: v[0] for k, v in d.items()}
{'a': 2, 'c': 1, 'b': 2, 'd': 1}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `dict()`

```
d = {'a': [2], 'b': [2], 'c': [1], 'd': [1]}
d = dict((k, v[0]) for k,v in d.items())
print(d)
```

**Output:**

```
{'a': 2, 'c': 1, 'b': 2, 'd': 1}
```